# For-loop and forEach() got weird behaviour

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop

I'm doing 5 requests, one after another. The first request is getting profile id and access token. And the others are downloading data for each profile id.

I'm doing `forEach()` and requesting data for every profile id I have. The strange things start when I'm reloading data. Most times it's right but sometimes it gets the data for index 1 first and then for 0. And I can't understand why. I tried `for item in id` and I tried to save profile ids into another array and use it but it has the same result. The one I didn't try is to tell exactly what index it should use. But I can't understand how the for-loop and request work together. Sometimes request are going one after another, sometimes not.

```
self.api.getProfileData(access_token: token) { (profiles, err)  in
    if err != nil {
        print("ERROR: \(err!)")
    } else {
        if let profile = profiles {
            let id = profile[0].data.profiles
            let token = profile[0].data.access_token
            if self.didLogin == true {
                self.profileId = id
            }
            self.group.enter()
            var i = 0
            id.enumerated().forEach({ (index, prof) in
                self.api.getProfiles(token: token!, profileId: prof.id!, completion: { (profileArray) in
                    debugPrint("PROFILES: \(prof.id!) At index: \(index)")
                    if let profileArray = profileArray {
                        self.profile = profileArray
                    }
                    self.api.getMarks(token: token!, profileId: prof.id!, completion: { (marksArray) in
                        debugPrint("MARKS: \(prof.id!) At index: \(index)")
                        if let marksArray = marksArray {
                            self.marks = marksArray
                        }
                        self.api.getBUP(token: token!, profileId: prof.id!, completion: { (bup) in
                            debugPrint("BUP: \(prof.id!) At index: \(index)")
                            if let bup = bup {
                                self.bup = bup
                            }
                            self.api.getRUP(token: token!, profileId: prof.id!, completion: { (rup) in
                                debugPrint("RUP: \(prof.id!) At index: \(index)")
                                if let rup = rup {
                                    self.rup = rup

                                    i += 1
                                    if i == profile[0].data.profiles.count {
                                        self.group.leave()
                                    }
                                }
                            })
                        })
                    })
                })
                self.group.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                    if i != profile[0].data.profiles.count {
                        i += 1
                    } else {
                        SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                        UIView.transition(with: self.tableView, duration: 0.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
                            //                                                if self.didLogin == true {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            //                                                }
                        }, completion: {(completed) in
                            if completed {
                                self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                                self.didLogin = false
                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        }
    }
}
```

I expect something like:

```
"PROFILES: 5176 At index: 0"
"PROFILES: 5177 At index: 1"
"MARKS: 5176 At index: 0"
"MARKS: 5177 At index: 1"
"BUP: 5176 At index: 0"
"BUP: 5177 At index: 1"
"RUP: 5176 At index: 0"
"RUP: 5177 At index: 1"
```

But I get:

```
"PROFILES: 5176 At index: 0"
"PROFILES: 5177 At index: 1"
"MARKS: 5177 At index: 1"
"MARKS: 5176 At index: 0"
"BUP: 5177 At index: 1"
"BUP: 5176 At index: 0"
"RUP: 5176 At index: 0"
"RUP: 5177 At index: 1"
```

or

```
"PROFILES: 5176 At index: 0"
"PROFILES: 5177 At index: 1"
"MARKS: 5177 At index: 1"
"MARKS: 5176 At index: 0"
"BUP: 5176 At index: 0"
"BUP: 5177 At index: 1"
"RUP: 5176 At index: 0"
"RUP: 5177 At index: 1"
```

Comment: Not *weird*, that's **expected** behavior. Every API with `completion` works asynchronously. `DispatchGroup` notifies when all tasks are completed but it does not guarantee the order.

Comment: Use [OperationQueue](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-use-multithreaded-operations-with-operationqueue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call,

```
id.enumerated().forEach({ (index, prof) in { ... }
```

Its an `asynchronous` call. It seems there are two element in id array and two root calls are being branched out from .forEach. For each call there are 4 Logs bening printed. four logs for profile 5176 and other four logs for profile 5177.

You should know that `asynchronous` call cannot guarantee you the order of the execution of two threads. That means logs order for profile 5176 and 5177 are not expected to be sequential but the all the logs under single profiles i.e 5176 are sequential as they are printed on each completion.

Please have a deep understanding on how [asynchronous and synchronous](https://medium.com/swift2go/writing-cleaner-asynchronous-code-in-swift-using-promise-pattern-f608254a349c) call flow work.